# Visual studio 2010 Ultimate Web Test Concurrent Users

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to do a performance test on an asp.net website. I have recorded a simple scenario with user login. I have created a data file containing 500 login ids and passwords. The application database also has this information. My intention is to run the test to analyze how the system behaves when 500 users tries to login and logout together. I want to run this scenario repeatedly for 1 hour. I am not sure how to achieve this using Visual studio 2010 ultimate edition. If anybody has an idea on this. Please do share.

Thanks in advance

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [WebTestPlugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to achieve that.

Basically, in the PreWebTest method, you can do something like this :

`e.WebTest.Context ["Login"] = "Random login from file";
    e.WebTest.Context ["Password"] = "Corresponding password";`

Then, in your webTest, you can plug the value from the context in the form post parameters using `{{Login}}` and `{{Password}}` in the value field.